# How to log highscores to a different HTML page through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a quiz for school that cycles through a few selected questions with a timer counting down, and when a user selects an incorrect answer the timer loses 10 seconds. Once the questions have run out my website gives a prompt asking for the users initials, and once they have input their initials I want it to log their name and score(time remaining) to a "highscores" page.

I have gotten all the questions, timer, HTML, etc working, but I am totally stumped on how I can log the user's name and score to the highscores page. If anybody could help I would greatly appreciate it, as I'm getting a bit frustrated! The highscores page also has a "clear highscores" button, but I feel like I should be able to get that working if I can work out how to plot down the names/scores.

Here is my HTML for the highscores page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Coding Quiz: Highscores</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Main Highscore Text -->

    <main class="row text-center d-flex justify-content-center pt-5 mb-3">
        <section class="card text-center d-flex">
            <h1 class="card-header">
            Highscores
            </h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text" id="eeee">
                    Your Highscore's are: 
                </p>
                <td id='highscoresTable'>

                </td>
                <a href="quiz-assignment.html" class="btn btn-primary ml-3">
                    Go Back
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary ml-4" id="clear-highscores">
                    Clear Highscores
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

<!-- End of Main Highscore Text -->
    <script text= "javascript" src="./quiz-assignment.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my Javascript for the entire project:

```
let timeLeft = document.getElementById("countdown");
let userHighscoresTable = document.getElementById('eeee');


let quizTime = 75;
let questionNumber = 0;
let score = 0;

let choiceA = document.getElementById('choiceA'),
    choiceB = document.getElementById('choiceB'),
    choiceC = document.getElementById('choiceC'),
    choiceD = document.getElementById('choiceD'),
    questionText = document.getElementById('questionText');

let questionsTable = [
    { question : "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    answerA : "strings",
    answerB : "booleans",
    answerC : "alerts",
    answerD : "numbers",
    correctAnswer : "C" 
    },

    { question: "Arrays in JS can be used to store",
    answerA : "Numbers and strings",
    answerB : "Other arrays",
    answerC : "Booleans",
    answerD : "All of the above",
    correctAnswer : "D"
    },

    { question: "The condition in an if / else statement is enclosed within ____." ,
    answerA : "Quotes",
    answerB : "Curly brackets",
    answerC : "Parentheses",
    answerD : "Square Brackets",
    correctAnswer : "C"
    },

    { question: "String values must be enclosed within ___ when being assigned to variables.",
    answerA : "Commas",
    answerB : "Curly brackets",
    answerC : "Quotes",
    answerD : "Parentheses",
    correctAnswer : "C"
    },

    { question: "A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is:",
    answerA : "Javascript",
    answerB : "terminal / bash",
    answerC : "for loops",
    answerD : "console.log",
    correctAnswer : "D"
    }
];


StartDownCounting();

function StartDownCounting() {       
    let interval = setInterval( () => { 
        if (quizTime <= 75 && quizTime >= 11) { 
            timeLeft.style.color = "green"; 
        }
        else if (quizTime <= 10 && quizTime >= 0) {
            timeLeft.style.color = "red";
        }

        timeLeft.innerText = quizTime;
        quizTime -= 1;

        if (quizTime < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert("Time's up, try again")
            location.href = './quiz-assignment.html';
            
        }
    }, 1000);
}



StartDisplayingQuestions()

function StartDisplayingQuestions() {
    let qst = questionsTable[questionNumber];
    questionText.innerText = qst.question;
    choiceA.textContent = qst.answerA;
    choiceB.textContent = qst.answerB;
    choiceC.textContent = qst.answerC;
    choiceD.textContent = qst.answerD;
}

function VerifyAnswer(answer) {
    if (answer === questionsTable[questionNumber].correctAnswer) {
         questionNumber++;
         score++;

    if (questionNumber < questionsTable.length) {
         StartDisplayingQuestions();
         }
    }

    else {
        quizTime = parseInt(timeLeft.innerText);
        quizTime -= 10;
        timeLeft.innerText = quizTime;
    }

    if (score === 5) {
        let collectUserName = prompt('Your score is: [ ' + quizTime + ' ] Please enter your initials in the box below.')
        location.href = './highscores.html'
    }
}
```

Thank you so much to anybody who takes the time to help me, I'm getting desperate!

Comment: Let me know if you would like me to provide the Home & Questions pages as well

Comment: If you want the high scores to be visible to different users you’ll have to store them on a server somewhere so they can either be delivered with the page or fetched on-demand. This is a pretty broad topic and can’t be answered in just a few words. If you just want it to work within the confines of the browser, where each browser has their own independent record and doesn’t know about anyone else’s you could use localStorage from the web storage api to persist them in the browser.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have given more background, this is just a school assignment and will never actually be posted online, so as long as I can get it to show up in the Highscores HTML page then I'm good to go. I'll look into localStorage, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `localStorage` API - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
function doIt(text) {
  localStorage.setItem('txt', text)
}

document.querySelector('input').value = localStorage.getItem('txt')
```

```html
<input oninput='doIt(this.value)'>
```

Note that it will not work inside this code snippet since it uses an iframe

`localStorage` persists over pages, so you can get the score on more than one page.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/nr21wau7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where/how in the JS file could I apply this? Very, very new to coding

Comment: @LouisYacksmith You could apply it anywhere. Also, could you click the check mark next to my answer to accept it? It helps future visitors, *and* gives you reputation!